# I need to output data from activity to a fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, kotlin

When the application starts, null is displayed.

I think that I am not correctly assigning a value to the TextView.

```
class MyFragment : Fragment() {
    private lateinit var textView: TextView

    companion object {
        private val TEXT_FIELD = "text_field"
        @JvmStatic
        fun newInstance(text_field: Int) = MyFragment().apply {
                        arguments = Bundle().apply {
                            putInt(TEXT_FIELD, text_field)
                        }
        }
    }

    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater,
        container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View? {
        val view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_my, container, false)

        textView = view!!.findViewById(R.id.text_view)
        textView.text = "${arguments?.getInt(TEXT_FIELD)}"

        return view
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You have `putInt` in assignment but you do `getString` when trying to retrieve the value.

Comment: Did you instantiate the Fragment like this `MyFragment.newInstance(123)`?

Comment: Yes, in OnCreate() in the Activity